# python3 error JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock in Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, speech-recognition

Im trying to do speech recognition but every time I run it I get this error.

JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock

Here is my code.

```
from gtts import gTTS
import playsound as ps
import speech_recognition as sr

sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names()

text=('text')
mic = sr.Microphone(device_index=20)
r = sr.Recognizer()

with mic as source:
    audio = r.listen(source)

re = r.recognize_google(audio)

def rSpeak():
    tts = gTTS(text)
    tts.save('hello.mp3')
    ps.playsound('hello.mp3', True)
rSpeak()
```

any help very appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to speak using this:

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id) 
def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()
speak('Hello, Sir.')
```

And if you want to recognize a voice then go with this:

```
import speech_recognition as sr 
def takeCommand():
    #It takes microphone input from the user and returns string output
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as mic:
        print("Listening...")
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(mic)
        audio = r.listen(mic)
    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
        print(f"User said: {query}\n")
    except Exception:
        print("Say that again please...")
        return "None"
    return query

query = takeCommand().lower()   #lower() is used to keep all your queries in lowercase.
```

And then you can match your query variable to match with the command you want to follow.